# scipy convolve depends on x

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

I am trying to convolve a lognormal PDF and a gaussian PDF. I therefor defined the functions in the following way:

```
def PDF_log(x,sig,mu): # log normal PDF
   mu = np.log(mu)
   return( (1/x)*(1/(sig*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))) * np.exp(-(np.log(x)-mu)**2/(2*sig**2)) )   

def gauss(x,sig,mu): # a noraml PDF
   return( 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sig**2)) * np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sig**2)) )

def gauss_log(x, sig, mu, sig0, mu0):
    a = signal.convolve(PDF_log(x,sig,mu),gauss(x,sig0,mu0),mode='same')/np.sum(gauss(x,sig0,mu0)) 


def test():
    mu = 0.6
    sig = 0.2
    sig0 = 0.05
    mu0 = mu
    x = np.linspace( 0.5, 0.6, 10000 )
    plt.plot( x, gauss_log(x, sig, mu, sig0, mu0), '--', label='gauss_X_log', zorder=10 )
    plt.plot( x, gauss(x,sig0,mu0), label='gauss' )
    plt.plot( x, PDF_log(x,sig,mu), label='log' )
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

This gives me the following result:

[image: first array domain]

The red line is the log-normal PDF, the green line the gaussian. The "convolution" is the blue dashed line. 
When I change the x domain `x = np.linspace( 0.5, 0.8, 10000 )` I get very different results:

[image: for different domain]

Clearly there is something wrong here. The result of my convolution integral `F(x) = int (g(t)*f(x-t))dt` should not depend on the range of "x". 
I then made the domain large, i.e. `x = np.linspace( 0.00001, 100, 10000 )`, which gives me this nonsense:

[image: large array domain]

Either there is a simple bug in my script or I missunderstand the discrete convolution.

Comment: You can compare your lognormal with `scipy.stats.lognorm`

Comment: I think my log-normal PDF is OK, at least I can match them when I use `scipy.stats.lognorm.pdf`. I simply copied the formula from Wikipedia. I suspect my problem lies within my understanding of what `scipy.signal.convolve` does (the blue dashed line in the plots).

Comment: @Sebastiano1991 to recover "expected results", you must convolve the signals over their whole domain (-infinity to infinity). For normal distributions, you can restrict the integration to "mean - a few times standard deviation" to "mean + a few times standard deviation" with reasonable accuracy but the domain is too small here.

Comment: That's what I was expecting - thus I increased the 'integration domain' in my third plot to [~0,100]. Is this still to small to the 'smaller then mean side', i.e. will this fail for all small mean? Is there a potential workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where I had my mistake:

rather than having a proper kernel function `gauss(x0,sig0,mu)`; I used the same `x` for the Gaussian.

This does what I think is correct (with the PDFs from above):

```
def gauss_log(x, x0, sig, mu, sig0, mu0):
    a = signal.convolve(gauss(x0,sig0,mu0),PDF_log(x,sig,mu),mode='same')/np.sum(gauss(x0,sig0,mu0))
    return( a )

def test(lightcurve,noisecurve):
    mu = 0.1 #can now put arbitrary small values of mu
    sig = 0.1
    sig0 = 0.05
    mu0 = 0
    x = np.linspace( 0.00001, 5, 1000 )
    x0 = np.linspace(-5,5,1000) #note that arrays need to be equal length!
    g_log = gauss_log(x, x0, sig, mu, sig0, mu0)
    plt.plot( x, g_log, '--', label='gauss_X_log', zorder=10 )
    plt.plot( x0, gauss(x0,sig0,mu0), label='gauss' )
    plt.plot( x, PDF_log(x,sig,mu), label='log' )
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    ###testing normalization!
    print(np.trapz(gauss(x0,sig0,mu0),x0))
    print(np.trapz(g_log,x))
    print(np.trapz(PDF_log(x,sig,mu),x))
```

1.0

0.999938903253

1.0

[image]

Comment: On a site note: `scipy.signal.convolve` is a discrete convolution of two arrays. For an large number of array points this works perfectly fine. In my actual case, where I only have 11 array entries, this causes problems. To circumvent this I opted to evaluate the convolution integral numerically with `scipy.integrate.quad`, which significantly improves the results at the cost of computation time. Alternatively one can pick values of  the PDFs that are most constraining, e.g. around the median.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to take the same x is easy explained if you consider x to be time for example. Now if you have two signals that are described with the time t, but you do not have the same x( or here t) array from which you constructed them; well then the times do not correspond correctly. At least the time **spacing needs to be the same** to work in a way that makes sense. I had a similar problem, where a laser pulse needs to be convolved with a concentration depending on time. The laser pulse is very sharp, meaning also short in time, so I take a small intervall t_laser and t_concentration is the whole time interval of my experiment:

```
t_laser = np.linspace(-20 ,20,160) 
t_concentration = np.linspace(-2000,20000,88000)
laser = laser_pulse(t_laser) ## Pulshape depending on time
concentration = ABC_model(t_concentration, some_parameters) ## Model for concentration(t)
```

Notice that for both time arrays I have the same spacing, leading to equal steps in time. If I had changed to

```
t_laser = np.linspace(-20 ,20,88000) 
t_concentration = np.linspace(-2000,20000,88000)
```

because I wanted a higher resolution for my laser pulse which should still go from t0=-20 to t1=20. But since I only convolve the laser with the signal,

```
signal.convolve(concentration, laser, mode='same')/sum(laser)
```

without taking the time arrays into account; one could interpret that the laser pulse has the same temporal extent, since it has the same length of the array.

Remark: Also you need to be aware, how the signal convolve function works (scipy.signal.fftconvolve). It seems to me it places the center of the laser array on the first element of the concentration array and then calculates the sum/integral. That is basically how a convolution with arrays works (But it is different from np.convolve; that would be mode "full"). So if you choose the array for your Gaussian function not to be symmetric, the maximum of the Gaussian is not in the center of the array (regarding the index), so your result shifts in the x direction.